# How to unflag a comment

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged a comment before doing any research on the answer - I feel bad because the user is highly ranked on the website? This was on the Movies and TV category. How do I unflag the comment?

Comment: Meh, don't worry that much about it. Comment flags aren't really that serious. I mean, we do properly look at them and take the necessary actions, but noone will blame anyone for a single wrong flag on a comment (especially since we don't really know who flags comments at all).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson thank you :) crisis averted! :D

Comment: That being said, a comment that points to a possible match for an ID question isn't bad at all, even if the respective user was *not* highly reputed or if the suggestion is plain wrong. That's why it's just a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I flagged with the comment "wrong suggestion" and then researched the comment - I'm sure it'll be ignored and not passed as a valid flag. I hope anyway! @NapoleonWilson

Comment: It already has been ignored long ago. ;-)

Comment: Suuuuuuuuuper :D @NapoleonWilson

Comment: And as a related hint. If you ever happen to accidentally flag an answer with something more serious (like "not an answer") and are not sure if the moderators will figure it out themselves, you can just leave another custom flag on the same post explaining the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. But don't worry about it!

Our mods here are quite thorough and they'll likely just mark your flag as unhelpful after checking out what you've flagged... and that's it.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to get in touch with the user to apologise :P

Comment: @ChelseaOwen No need for that really, the user doesn't even know you flagged his comment.

Comment: Great :) @NapoleonWilson